# How to use the same value in a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

`_stats.value()` is a resolved promise itself. Many methods need it as you can see below. All of these methods accept `_stats` as an argument.

To keep things simple, I use only method names, without calling functions inside functions *OR* returning `_stats` from methods.

**I want to make it simpler by removing `.return` calls**

```js
return Promise.resolve()
  .then(removeYesterdayKeys)
  .then(renameTodayKeys).return(_stats.value())
  .then(removeStatsOfToday).return(_stats.value())
  .then(addStatsOfToday).return(_stats.value())
  .tap(console.log.bind(console))
```

Comment: Do you actually need to execute them in sequence?

Comment: What do all these methods return?

Comment: @Bergi yes, they're serial. These method do not return anything. For example: removeStatsOfToday(stats)

Comment: Do you really mean "not return anything", or do they return promises that fulfill with `undefined`? And if they need to be serial, you'd typically return (resolve with) the thing that the next step is waiting for (if there is no such thing, they wouldn't need to run sequentially).

Comment: Yes, of course they return a promise, they're in the chain as in the example. Actually, i want the pieces (methods) do not depend on another so that I don't return _stats from them. I'm kind of mediating between them through then chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, with underscore you can do it like this:

```
var feedStatsTo = function(f) { return _.partial(f, statsOfToday); };

return Promise.resolve()
  .then(removeYesterdayKeys)
  .then(renameTodayKeys)

  .then(feedStatsTo(removeStatsOfToday))
  .then(feedStatsTo(addStatsOfToday))

  .return(statsOfToday)
  .tap(console.log.bind(console))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach several `.then` to a single promise:

```
var p = Promise.resolve('foo');
p.then(bar);
p.then(baz);
```

Both `bar` and `baz` will receive `'foo'` as their argument.

However, chaining to a `.then` means the next function will receive the output of the previous `.then` as argument:

```
p.then(bar).then(baz);
```

`baz` receives whatever `bar` returns.

That's the way it works, pick which one is useful for your situation. Perhaps a single callback which executes `bar` and `baz` inside it would be most useful? Promises are only supposed to solve *asynchronous* execution problems; don't use them for synchronous code just because the chains look nice.

Comment: Thanks but this is not a solution I was looking for. I also disagree on promises are only for async problem solving. They are also for preventing pyramid of doom. And I want to keep my code simple.

Comment: @deeperx Promises don't prevent pyramids of doom in synchronous code (example, nested `if(){}`s or `for(){}`s. They only solve callback-based pyramid of dooms, which are almost exclusively async.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Of course, I was talking in async sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `.return()` calls, and don't want to change your methods, your only choice is to pass function expressions:

```
return _stats.value().then(function(stats) {
    return removeYesterdayKeys()
      .then(renameTodayKeys)
      .then(function(_) { return removeStatsOfToday(stats); })
      .then(function(_) { return addStatsOfToday(stats); })
      .then(function(_) { console.log(stats); return stats; });
});
```

or, more closely to your original example, but not necessarily better:

```
return removeYesterdayKeys()
  .then(renameTodayKeys)
  .then(function(_) { return _stats.value().then(removeStatsOfToday); })
  .then(function(_) { return _stats.value().then(addStatsOfToday; })
  .then(function(_) { return _stats.value().tap(console.log.bind(console)) });
```

If you are looking for a really elegant way, you should of course take a peek at the async/await proposal (and its experimental implementations).

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted know if there is a better way. I see now that there is not right now. I'm very excited about async/await.